# python code not works in Sublime text 3, but works on repl.it

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Sublime build system is Python default.
Why it works on repl.it ide?

```
def calculate_pi(n_terms: int) -> float:
numerator: float = 4.0
denominator: float = 1.0
operation: float = 1.0
pi: float = 0.0
for _ in range(n_terms):
    pi += operation * (numerator / denominator)
    denominator += 2.0
    operation *= -1.0
return pi
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(calculate_pi(1000000))

Syntax error
    def calculate_pi(n_terms: int) -> float:
                            ^
```

Comment: Are you using the same python version?

Comment: The Python version embedded in Sublime doesn't support type annotations, it's an older version

Comment: Sublime's embedded Python is used for plugins only, so unless the code above is part of an esoteric plugin of some sort, I don't think that's the issue. However, the build system that it uses executes `python`, which may not be the same version as you think it is, as @ToTheMax mentioned above.